# how to convert a text file into google doc using google docs api

Tags: node.js, google-docs-api

I have the output of OCRed files that I need to convert into a Google Doc. The best closest use case I have seen is the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/docs-ml-transcript#5) to convert speech into a Google Doc. However I cannot figure out if those calls exist in the node.js libs, and if not how to get this done. Some guidance on how to use the `batchUpdate` to create a bunch of requests along with paragraphs/line breaks would be nice, and specifically how to do this index calculation.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `i presume if i just create JSON based off of an example doc wont work?`. If you want to convert the text to Google Document, how about using Drive API? But, I cannot understand the details of your goal. For example, will you use the Google APIs with OAuth2 or the service account or others? And, will you use [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) or others? I thought that when you add more information about your goal, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Tanaike, thanks for responding! i have seen your responses earlier and you seem to be pretty good in your responses and english :) not to worry. regarding the JSON and example doc: What i was thinking of was to create document in the google drive with some example text, get the JSON with docs.documents.get() and then modify/append the json with the text that i need.

Comment: for why i m not using the drive api to just convert text into doc is that one of the requirement i have is to put the text in their appropriate pages, meaning put text of page 1 of the OCRed book in the page 1 of the document, so it is easier to review. Can that be done with the drive api?

Comment: and sorry yes i will be using googleapis and node.js

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, new Document including the text content cannot be achieved using the create method of Docs API. This is from `Creates a blank document using the title given in the request. Other fields in the request, including any provided content, are ignored.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create) So, I proposed to convert the text file to Document using Drive API. In that case, you can retrieve the values using the get method of Docs API. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi there @user1644058! @Tanaike is right in his comment. Though you could first use [`documents.create`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create) to create a Doc, and then use [`documents.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate). Would that be a valid approach for your situation?

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron - yes that is what i m trying to do, just needed more info about how to use batchUpdate

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I will assume that your goal is to translate a TXT file to a Doc. If my assumption is correct, then you can upload the TXT document easily by following these steps. First of all you should make a [`documents.create`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create) request in order to create the Doc itself. Read its response, because you will need the field `revisionId` later. Then you only need to send a [`documents.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) request like this example:

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "location": {
          "index": 1
          
        },
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec erat eget nisl facilisis luctus vitae ac lorem. Quisque lobortis iaculis massa, in mattis lorem eleifend eu. Vivamus ac placerat nisi. Vivamus odio nulla, faucibus ac lobortis vel, sodales vel velit. Nam quam ex, posuere in risus quis, pretium euismod lectus. Donec accumsan varius tellus, vitae suscipit ipsum scelerisque sit amet. Vestibulum ut dapibus enim. Nam et eros gravida, vulputate libero eu, pellentesque odio. Sed tempus ante non metus imperdiet varius. Phasellus ut lacus sapien. Suspendisse vestibulum eleifend felis finibus sollicitudin. Nam quis vehicula lectus, in convallis eros. \nEtiam vel erat id dui commodo faucibus. Pellentesque ac lacinia libero. Nunc blandit elementum nunc, at mattis eros tincidunt ac. Duis vitae scelerisque nisl, venenatis venenatis purus. Fusce felis lacus, blandit ac quam vitae, vulputate vestibulum felis. Morbi aliquam mauris metus, eget venenatis orci pretium eu. Nam cursus eget dolor ut tempor. \nSed turpis dolor, finibus pharetra elit sed, pulvinar semper nisi. Quisque sed iaculis purus. Quisque aliquet feugiat augue vel feugiat. Mauris in est vel elit aliquet luctus cursus quis nibh. Nam condimentum velit felis, vitae hendrerit lacus imperdiet non. Nam luctus quam et tortor tempus luctus. Aenean aliquam nibh vel varius scelerisque. Sed sit amet tortor lacus. Curabitur ullamcorper, justo non vulputate dapibus, lorem ex ultrices arcu, non efficitur nulla nisl vitae ante. Ut quis sem sit amet mi ultrices pulvinar quis nec nunc. \nEtiam bibendum neque nec dui finibus blandit. Proin tincidunt purus id ante interdum, eget convallis sem dictum. Proin quis justo vitae ligula sagittis rhoncus. Nulla at arcu et orci iaculis ornare. Maecenas eget neque maximus, dignissim urna eu, efficitur turpis. Aenean tempor elit sed eleifend luctus. Suspendisse in auctor sapien. Nunc condimentum libero in lacus ornare gravida. Curabitur id felis nunc. Fusce sed pellentesque nunc. Morbi ligula odio, ornare hendrerit arcu id, dignissim mollis turpis. \nAliquam est dolor, consectetur ac imperdiet vel, imperdiet id dolor. Praesent ut pellentesque felis. Cras eget dictum nunc. Vestibulum nec nulla ut ipsum vestibulum scelerisque. Vivamus quis lorem sem. Cras vitae finibus dolor. Vivamus et nibh orci. Vestibulum vel justo ullamcorper, dapibus neque quis, iaculis lectus. Donec sagittis, tellus at tincidunt varius, est augue suscipit magna, nec sagittis elit diam id libero. Nam est eros, maximus sed malesuada id, pulvinar eget nulla. Donec ullamcorper ligula vel massa aliquam, nec bibendum sem fringilla. Nunc vestibulum dignissim augue, vitae pretium risus mattis non. Etiam ante tortor, tincidunt vitae velit at, posuere congue nulla."
        
      }
      
    }
    
  ],
  "writeControl": {
    "targetRevisionId": "{YOUR TARGET REVISION ID}"
    
  }
}
```

I used a [lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) text as a model. Please keep in mind that pagebreaks are depicted with the `\n` glyph. Update the `text` field with your desired text and write the `targetRevisionId` from the previous step into the homonymous field. At this point the Doc should be updated with your goal text.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 2 questions, 1 - i m confused about location part. Since its going to be multiple requests, is that going to be index:1+length of text in the previous request? and 2 - how do i add a page break in there just have \n in there (or did you mean \p?).. thanks again!

Comment: About the first question, that `index` is the indicator of where the text will be inserted. If you wish to append the text at the end of an existing paragraph, then you would have to know the `endIndex` by using the [`document.get()`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get). If you want to add the text at some point in the middle of the existing text, then you would only have to adapt the `index`. Here you can learn more about the [`location`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#location).

Comment: In relation to your second doubt, you should use the `\n` symbol for page breaks (not `\p`). Please test this approach and share your findings.